# Accessing the value of an int which has been modified in another

Tags: objective-c, class, variables

Apologizes if this is an obvious question. I have a VC A and a VC B(which is a subclass of A). In A's .m I have a int Counter called currentQuestion. If the user enters the wrong answer VC A goes to VC B. In B i want to access the current value of currentQuestion in order to place the correct image in leftImageViewer.  It does seem to recognise currentQuestion as a variable already instantiated but does not show the correct value.

```
leftImageViewer.image = [UIImage imageNamed:left[currentQuestion]];
```

Comment: Can you post the code of how you go to VC B ?

Comment: `- (IBAction)SelectC:(id)sender {
    
    if ([self.correctAns isEqualToString:@"C"]) {
     
    [self showNextQuestion];
    }
    else{
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueToB" sender:nil];
    }
}`

Comment: I think you could use the sender parameter in your 'perform segueWithIdentifier:sender: When you pass self as sender you can access the instance variables of VC A in VC B using sender.variable

Answer (score 0):

You will have to pass the value of `currentQuestion` to `VCB`, since VCB is creating entirely new instances of all the instance variables (or that is what generally happens, hard to tell with outseeing the code):

```
// an example of how to create 'VCB', this is NOT in 'VCB.m'
VCB *vcb = [[VCB alloc] init];
[vcb setCurrentQuestion:[self currentQuestion]];
// present 'vcb' how you are doing so now
```

Of course, this is assuming you have a property `@property int currentQuestion`.

More generally, you would want look at the concepts of [inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29) and [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming) to have a better understanding of what is happening.

**UPDATE**:

Your `VCA` should look like:

```
@interface VCA : UIViewController
    // ...
@property int currentQuestion; // this will allow 'currentQuestion' to be accessible
    // ...
@end
```

To understand why and how this will work, I encourage you to get a better understanding of how inheritance works. It is a fundamental concept in object oriented programming.

Comment: This part would go into the .m of VCB?  Yes I have declared `@interface AVC : ViewController{
    int currentQuestion;
    }`

Comment: This should go in the place where you initialize VC B. As @Mike D has written, when creating a new instance of VC B it won't know the value of the currentQuestion variable regardless it is a subclass of VC A.

Comment: @Sfocker See my update. But there is an important concept involved here that is used in all higher level languages, frameworks, and SDKs.

Comment: Mike. Thanks for the update. I do think I have a firm grasp of what your saying to an extent. A is the rootclass, B in inheriting from A. Everything declared in A is available to use in B, but its just another instance of currentQuestion. Its not the actual value of currentQuestion in AVC's. Have I this correct?

Comment: @Sfocker That is correct. When you create an instance of `VCB`, you are getting a new instance of `currentQuestion`, same with all the other instance variables and properties declared in VCA.

Comment: Okay. I do not understand where this code goes
`VCB *vcb = [[VCB alloc] init];
[vcb setCurrentQuestion:[self currentQuestion]];` 

Just before I call the VCB segue in the VCA?

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working for Me. Should I have VCB imported into VCA or anything like that?

Comment: @Sfocker I think with that, it might be easier at this to declare a protocol that both view conttrollers can adopt and remove the inheritance component. I'll update in afew minutes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15531352/accessing-the-value-of-a-variable-in-the-root-class-from-a-subclass @MikeD here is a more comprehensive look at my problem it may help.Thankyou