# Accessing the value of a variable in the Root class from a subclass

Tags: ios, xcode, class, variables

I really can not figure this one out. 
I have a VC called additionalMathViewController which displays questions to the user. If the user answers incorrectly the user is directed to another VC which is a subclass of additionalMathViewController called incorrectViewController.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface additionalmathViewController : ViewController{
int currentQuestion;
}
```

currentQuestion is a counter variable which increases everything the user gets a question right and another question can be displayed. if the user get the question wrong I want to go to incorrectViewController. Here is my code

```
- (IBAction)SelectA:(id)sender {
if ([self.correctAns isEqualToString:@"A"]) {
       [self showNextQuestion];
}
else{
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"segueToIncorrect" sender:nil];
}
}
```

If the user selects A and it is correct show another question. If it is wrong perform Segue to incorrectViewController

```
#import "additionalmathViewController.h"
@interface IncorrectImageViewController : additionalmathViewController
```

Here I want to grab the value of currentQuestion from additionalMathViewController

```
incorrectImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:left[currentQuestion]];
```

This current image is not the value from the additionalmathViewController

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you asking this question again? It was correctly answered in your other question posted an hour ago. Richard's answer below is the same as MikeD's answer.

Comment: I thought my question was vague and we did not come to an answer so I thought it better to repost with more comprehensive outlook

Comment: Try to modify your current answer next time instead of posting a new one about the same thing but presented with different words.

Comment: Okay thanks sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new view controller is a new instance, therefore has no idea what the previous instance had for a value.  You need to pass your currentQuestion value to the new controller in `prepareForSegue` method.

Make currentQuestion a property

```
@interface IncorrectImageViewController
  @property (copy) NSInteger currentQuestion;
..
```

And then in the prepareForSegue set the value on the destination controller.

```
@implementation additionalmathViewController

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    IncorrectImageViewController *incorrect = [segue destinationViewController];
    incorrect.currentQuestion = self.currentQuestion;
}
```

Comment: IncorrectImageViewController is the name of the subclass>? Yes?

Comment: In my IncorrectImageViewController I am getting the error undeclared identifier 'currentQuestion'
In the prepare to segue do I need to name the segue?

Comment: Did you add the @property to the `IncorrectImageViewController`?

Comment: No? @property for which, the currentQuestion as I did that previously in additionalmathViewController

Comment: The property belongs on the subclass.

Comment: yes I have this in my subclass `@property  NSInteger incorrect;`

Comment: Look again at the answer.  The property name is `currentQuestion`.

Comment: Yes but in the IncorrectImageViewController you stated above.
You will need to clarify here please I am very confused

Comment: I edited the answer, hope that helps because there's already too much chat on this answer.

Comment: `incorrect.currentQuestion = self.currentQuestion;` in this line I am creating a new IncorrectImage object called incorrect which is assigned the same value as current question .
Then in my .h of IncorrectImage I have `@property int incorrect;`

Comment: Yes I have done all of this before and it gives the error property with 'copy'attribute must be of object type? beside the `@property (copy) NSInteger currentQuestion;`